# AS3 keyboard animated character - Compiler errors all over the place despite following tutorial to the letter

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Trying to create a 2D character that responds to keyboard inputs in Flash Professional CC.  Every YouTube tutorial my son and I have tried produces Compiler errors and NOTHING works.

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var rightKeyIsDown:Boolean = false;
var leftKeyIsDown:Boolean = false;
var upKeyIsDown:Boolean = false;
var downKeyIsDown:Boolean = false;

var playerSpeed:int = 7;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pressAKey);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, releaseAKey);

function pressAKey(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
{
    rightKeyIsDown = true;
}
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
{
    leftKeyIsDown = true;
}
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
{
    upKeyIsDown = true;
}
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
{
    downKeyIsDown = true;
}
}   

function releaseAKey(event.KeyboardEvent):void
{
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
{
    rightKeyIsDown = false;
}
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
{
    leftKeyIsDown = false;
}
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
{
    upKeyIsDown = false;
}
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
{
    downKeyIsDown = false;
}
}

player_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveThePlayer);

function moveThePlayer(event:Event):void
{       
if(rightKeyIsDown == true)
{
    player_mc.x += playerSpeed;
}

if(leftKeyIsDown == true)
{
    player_mc.x -+ playerSpeed;
}
}
```

What is wrong with the above code?  We have followed this tutorial, which seems very straightforward however the minute we type in a curly bracket it highlights in red, and then when we try to test we receive Compiler Errors.

> Scene 1, Layer 'Player', Frame 1, Line 35, Column 27   1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before dot.

We are using Flash Professional CC and AS3 - is there a better resource for tutorials for this type of thing as we're being driven mad having tried at least 5 of these now without success.

Would really appreciate some advice on why the above is wrong and also where we might find tutorials that actually work!

Thank you.
NJ & Son!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I threw your code into Flash and did not see any issues surrounding mismatching parenthesis; however, I did notice the following errors

First, In the following if control structure:

```
if(leftKeyIsDown == true)
{
    player_mc.x -+ playerSpeed;
}
```

You are attempting to use an operator of `-+` but no such operator exists in Flash ActionScript.  I'm thinking you meant to do the following instead:

```
if(leftKeyIsDown == true)
{
    player_mc.x -= playerSpeed;
}
```

Second, the issue is right here:

```
function releaseAKey(event.KeyboardEvent):void
{
    // your code
}
```

You need a `:` to specify the datatype. Can't believe I missed that. So it should be:

```
function releaseAKey(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    // your code
}
```

I was able to plug this code into Flash CC and get it to compile with no errors. Cheers!

Comment: PO shows a piece of code but there's no guaranty that it's the one code producing the error.

Comment: Now we get the following compile error - 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before dot.  Line 35 being:  function releaseAKey(event.KeyboardEvent):void

Comment: @NathonJones, I found it! see my updated post. Cheers!

Comment: Brilliant, thank you Sky. Do you know what I'd need to add to allow the character to move up and down too, based on input of the UP and DOWN keys?  Also, is it possible to have a character move when the user move the mouse - in other words a character that tracks the mouse movements?  We are well chuffed we've got our character moving though!  Thank you.

Comment: @NathonJones, You're welcome. To move your characters up and down, simply follow the model for the right and left movement, but alter the function names to reflect up and down, and instead of using the `.x` property, use the `.y` property. you already have the boolean flags `upKeyIsDown` and `diownKeyIsDown` is down to get you started. And using the mouse is possible, will take more code to get that down, but there are multiple ways to accomplish that.